# Can't load google map data

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I use google javascript API v3 to load map and generate some markers. It works well when I deploy and run it on windows, but It failed to load map data when I deploy it on linux.
Here is the code to load:

```
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $place[0]->lat?>,<?php echo $place[0]->lng?>),
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"),
        myOptions);
}
```

Can anyone let me know what's wrong?

This problem is solved. The problem is that the order of lat & lng is wrong on my linux server.

Comment: Looks fine, do you get any errors on console, what $place[0] returns ?

Comment: Have you compared the code and see what is different? Are there and errors in the console of the browser?

Comment: I print out $place[0] ([1]) and it look okay: 21.011791/105.849221.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no error appears in the console. So I don't know where to spot the problem. Source code is the same on both environment for sure.

Comment: Since the resulting HTML is the same on both Windows and Linux, maybe there's something else going on? Try loading this simple one-marker map in Linux http://jsfiddle.net/BjsgH/

Comment: It does not work either. But I've just check Chrome console and saw those error:  GET http://www.superfish.com/ws/js/base_single_icon.js?ver=11.0.6.8 404 (Not Found)
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=src:apiv3,ts:1336316311448".
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_ads&cad=src:apiv3,ads:0".

Comment: And on firefox, there is no such kind of error.

Comment: For the last 2 errors, Does this mean  that there is something wrong with Apache configuration? eg. Mime type?

Comment: I heard a lot of people seeing the MIME type warning, I get them all the time (I'm surprised you don't see them on Windows too, even when everything loads fine). When you say the map doesn't work on Linux, you mean no map appears (it is blank or grey), or the markers don't appear? Also I have never seen the superfish error.

Comment: @TranDucVuong I just thought of something; since you said the jsfiddle page I gave you didn't load, there's probably nothing wrong with your Apache server or Google maps code, I'm thinking there's some setting with incoming data that is blocking google maps tile images from showing, like a proxy setting?

Comment: I've just tested and found that when I pass number directly to LatLng constructor, it worked well, because LatLng API require parameters as number. So I use parseFloat to convert my variable to number. But It still does NOT work.

Comment: Thanks Mia Dilorenzo, I solved the problem. The order of lat, lng in my database on linux is wrong. such a stupid mistake :(
In conclusion: 
first of all, make sure the order of lat, lng is correct.
The 2nd thing is that we use parseLoat for parameter passed to LatLng constructor.

Comment: Please edit the original question text and close out the question.

Comment: i ask myself why is the code any different on the linux machine?

Comment: Problem is the database difference, it's not in the code.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and mark it accepted. It helps those of us that are looking to resolve unanswered questions.